# objective-c, psd, makeup

Tags: ios, layout

Does anybody know how to make correct image and (UIlabel)label position for iphone and ipad
according to the layout image in psd file.

I'm using photoshop. I take a ruler look for the highest letter in the sentence(which should be positioned) and move it to the top of psd image, than take the left extreme letter and move ruler to the left.

Then i make a screenshot of the ipad/iphone screen and compare the x,y of psd and png file.
if psd x/y more then png x/y i make the next steps: Xpsd - Xpng, Ypsd - Ypsd, and if the coordinates of psd less than png i make  Xpsd + Xpng, Ypsd + Ypsd.

And finally i have wrong visual position in ipad/iphone!

Answer (score 1):

The most common reasons why the visual position/dimensions of a given element don't match what you think they should is typically the auto resizing mask that is applied to the particular view in question.

For example, your `UILabel` should have its autoresizing mask set to:

```
label.autoResizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
```

This will keep your label aligned to the top left, and will not allow its height, nor its width to be changed depending on the super view's size changes.

This can also be set in interface builder with these controls:

[image]

The outer lines match the margin sizing, if it is a solid red line, then that means that as the superview's size changes, the current view's position relative to those edges will be preserved.

The Inner lines represent a flexible width, and height.  If it is a solid line, then that means that the current view will resize to retain the same proportion of the superview's size.